# Numerically integrating with trapezium rule between 0 and infinity of Sin(x)/sqrt(x) with C programming

Tags: c, integration, numerical-methods, numerical-integration

I am having a problem finding a good approximation to the integral between 0 and infinity of sin(x)/sqrt(x) in C programming. I am trying to use the trapezium rule. In my code I also want the user to input a precision value such as 0.001 where the output value will be accurate to that amount  of decimal places. What is going wrong with this code?

```js
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
int i, N; // integers to interate on in loops //
double h, x, y, precision, lowerLim = 0.0001, upperLim = 10000, f0, fN;

printf("accuracy:");
scanf("%lf", &precision);
N = 10;
double areastored, newarea; 
do {
    newarea = 0.0;
    areastored = newarea; // areastored is the area that I want to compare to the new area calulated as the N (number of partitions) to check the precision of the new value to see if it a better approximation //
    h = (upperLim - lowerLim)/(N-1);
    fN = sin(upperLim)/sqrt(upperLim);
    f0 = sin(lowerLim)/sqrt(lowerLim); // end points evaluated in function //
    newarea = newarea + 0.5*h*(f0 + fN); 

    for (int i = 1; i < N; i++) {
    x = lowerLim + h*i;
    y = sin(x)/sqrt(x);
    newarea = newarea + y*h;   // this loop adds all the middle trapezia areas //
    }

    printf("at N %d integral %f\n", N, newarea);
    N = N*5; // iterate the N so next round of the loop it will approximate an area with more and smaller trapezia //
} while ( fabs ( newarea - areastored ) > precision ); // if this is false then should have an area to the desired precision //

    printf("The integral evaluates to: %lf\n", newarea); 
}
```

The problem is that if I input an accuracy 0.01, the area is calculated for N = 10, 50, 250 but isn't able to continue and the last area = 8.53 which is off the value of 1.253... I'm expecting

EDIT: I have now made suggested changes to the above code as can be seen now thanks to the comments from several users below. Thank you very much for your help! I have now got an issue with my output, see the attached image of my terminal. It should have stopped by the 9th iteration of N for this input and so the printed vale is rather baffling. Why has this occured? Thanks again for any help in advance!

[image]

Comment: What makes you think that something is going wrong with your code?

Comment: @Yunnosch I had previously used an integral calulator to help me work out what my target value would be. The values that would pop up in the output of the program were very jumpy all over the place and also often the program wouldn't stop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two errors in your code

```
// ...
newarea = 0.0;                       // <-- It's initialized here
do {
    // ...
    h = (upperLim - lowerLim)/N-1;   // <-- This doesn't do what you think
    // ...
    // It's updated, but never reset 
    newarea = newarea + 0.5*h*(f0 + fN);
    // ...
} while ( ... );
```

You should move the `newarea = 0.0;` line inside the loop and modify the formula that calculates `h`.

Also note that you have a fixed upper limit (1000), while for this type of integrals you should consider an increasing upper limit and maybe a non uniform grid spacing.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I would like to be able to increase the upper limit and not keep it fixed. Would you have any futher guidance for me in order to acheive this?

Comment: Also change `for (x=lowerLim+h; x < upperLim; x+=h) {` to `for (int i = 1; i < N; ++i) { x = lowerLim + h*i;`. The former may perform one iteration too many due to floating-point rounding in managing `x`.

Answer (score 1):

If you debug your program you will see that

```
h = (upperLim - lowerLim)/N-1;
```

leads to a negative value of `h` for `N=1250`.

This leads to an endless loop

```
for (x=lowerLim+h; x < upperLim; x+=h) {
```

because when `x` gets to a large enough absolute value it will no longer change when you add `h`.

You probably mean

```
h = (upperLim - lowerLim) / (N-1);
```

Comment: Yes that is exactly my mistake! Thanks so much for your help!